# How is an string being hold by a pointer and not by an character array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, string

This code works perfectly; as you can see here `name` is a pointer. When I give a value to it, it is stored perfectly, but when I change the pointer to array the code breaks. Why do I need a pointer to store a string?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct student{
    char *name;
    int roll;
    int clas;
}*ptr,stu;

void main(){
    int i;
    int n;
    stu.roll=2;
    stu.name = "sum";
    printf("%d %s",stu.roll,stu.name);
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct student{
    char name[10];
    int roll;
    int clas;
}*ptr,stu;

void main(){
    int i;
    int n;

    stu.roll=2;
    stu.name = "sum";
    printf("%d %s",stu.roll,stu.name);
}
```

Comment: You don't need a pointer to store a string.  You need a memory location to store a string.  In the first case, you are assigning the location of the (first element of) the string constant to the pointer, and later using that pointer to access the memory to print the data.  In the second case, you have a syntax error because you cannot assign a string constant to an array.

Comment: @WilliamPursell This might be a stupid question but don't we store strings in character arrays in C? char name[10]="John" doesnot give any error, then why THIS particular problem throws one? If char name[10] = "John" is a bad way to assign strings, what is the BEST way?

Comment: `char name[] = "John";` is not an assignment.  It is an initialization.  Syntactically, it is a short cut for `char name[5] = { 'J', 'o', 'h', 'n', '\0'}`.   There is no similar syntactic sugar for `char name[5]; name = "John";`  That is just a syntax error.  You have to write `char name[5]; strncpy( name, "John", sizeof name);`

Comment: OT: regarding: `void main(){`  Per the C standard, there are only two(2) valid signatures for `main()` they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign to arrays. This doesn't have a meaning in C.

You want:

```
strcpy(stu.name,"sum");
```

Comment: If so how is this working?
`#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char arr[5] = "Rosha";
    printf("%s", arr);
}`

Comment: @sumanrajkhanal The example you give in your comment is undefined behavior, since a string with length 5 cannot fit in an array of size 5.

Comment: No undefined behaviour with the initialization - the null terminator will simply be omitted in this case (C11 6.7.9). But the subsequent printf does cause UB. Be careful!

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* to use a pointer to store strings. Arrays are pointers are two valid ways to deal with strings, and they are some way mutually bound with each other. You just need to understand what an array is and how are characters stored in them so that we can call them "strings".

---

First thing we need to remember: **what is a pointer (to a type `T`)?**

- It the address where data of type `T` is stored

Now, **what is an array** `T var[N]?

- It is a sequence of N elements of the same type `T` stored contiguously in memory.
- `var` is the name of the array, and represents the address of its first element of the array. It is *evaluated* like a pointer though **it's not a pointer**.

Almost there. **What is a string?**

- it is an array containing elements of type `char` terminated by a special *nul-terminator* character (`'\0')

---

So a string **IS** an array, but like every array can be evaluated as a pointer to its first element. And every pointer to `char` is a string if it is terminated by the null character, and be accessed with the array syntax:

```
char * str = "hello"; // contains 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'
                      // cannot be modified because it points to a constant area of memory

printf ("%c %c\n", str[1], str[4]); // prints "e o"

/********/

char str2[] = "hello"; // same contents as above, but thi one can be modified
```

---

**Note**: the assignment

```
stu.name = "sum";
```

is invalid because `name` is an array field of the `struct student` struct. As explained above an array **is not** a pointer, and one of the main differences is that it cannot be assigned (i.e. cannot be an *lvalue* in an assignment action). It will raise a compilation error.

The correct action is *copying* the data into the array using `strcpy()` function.